# Running MySQL on RPI / optimising query

Tags: mysql, sql, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry PI 3 running MySQL 5.5.57 - this is the only service running on the RPI. 
My app makes a key query (below) which takes 5-7 sec to execute on the MySQL server.

I have done a lot to optimize indexes and FK but it really hasn't helped much. When I do an explain I see that it is using temporary and filesort, which I don't really understand.

- Are there any configuration tweaks which should be done when running mysql on a RPI. I don't know much about the various buffers...
- Is there anything else I should do to optimise the query?

The table has about 30.000 rows and growing...

This is the query:

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE  distinct `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
WHERE (`photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') 
AND (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL) 
ORDER BY photos.date_taken DESC LIMIT 500 OFFSET 500;
```

This is the table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_taken` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `file_extension` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(16,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(16,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `phash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lg_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `md_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_date_taken` (`date_taken`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_status` (`status`),
  KEY `index_photos_on_phash` (`phash`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_47f4e5f105` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25672 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I do an explain on the query then this is what I get:

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys                                     | key                        | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | photos | range | index_photos_on_date_taken,index_photos_on_status | index_photos_on_date_taken | 9       | NULL              | 13147 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | facets | ref   | index_facets_on_photo_id                          | index_facets_on_photo_id   | 9       | pt_prod.photos.id |     1 | Using index; Distinct                        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query will at times be extended to:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `photos`.* 
FROM `photos`  
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `tags`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `comments`.`id` 
WHERE `photos`.`date_taken` >= '2017-01-25' 
AND `photos`.`date_taken` <= '2018-01-10' 
AND `locations`.`country_id` = 16 
AND `locations`.`city_id` = 21 
OR `facets`.`source_id` = 9 AND `facets`.`type` = 'AlbumFacet'
OR `facets`.`source_id` = 9  AND `facets`.`type` = 'TagFacet'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Your query is only using columns form the first table.  I would write it as:

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` p
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
WHERE (p.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') AND (NOT p.status <=> 1) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM facets f WHERE pid = f.photo_id)
ORDER BY p.date_taken DESC
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 500;
```

Removing the `SELECT DISTINCT` should be a bit win.  You should also have an index on `facets(photo_id)`.

An index on `(date_taken, status)` might help.  However, it is not clear how selective your conditions are, so an index on photos might not be of much use.

Comment: Did you intend to remove the join to facets, by replacing it with the EXISTS predicate? I guess so, because doing a semi-join that way would allow you to safely remove the DISTINCT modifier.

Comment: it does speed it up significantly - to 0.033 sec!  I'm doing this from a rails app, and I think it will take a bit of activerecord bending to get it to do this. That's why I wanted to find a solution on the mysql side. Do you think that the execution time of 5 sec is reasonable with the setup described

Comment: It is no problem to extend the activerecord with arel to include the nested query. Bu what if I need to extend the query with more conditions - see my edited question above.

Comment: @martin . . . It is rude to edit a question after it has been answered, because that can invalidate answers -- and invalid answers draw downvotes.